# Function type with required parameters does demand arguments upon function call

Tags: typescript

I'm a TypeScript learner and I'm going through different sources and courses, but I couldn't  find out how to make the compiler demand arguments for typed function.

The example is very simple: I have a function that needs two strings `firstName` and `lastName` and is supposed to return a concatenation of it:

```
type FuncType = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => string;
const getFullName: FuncType = () => "";
```

I am conscious of the fact that the function definition is not complete. But at this point (of writing the function definition) I would expect the compiler to warn me (or hint me) that I'm missing to specify two parameters (`firstName` and `lastName`) which are obviously required judging from the type `FuncType`.

That is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: That is definitely weird, however I don't think it makes a difference (?). You still need to call `getFullName` with 2 parameters, or else typescript complains.  `getFullName` can have 0-2 parameters, if it uses them is (apparently) not important.

Answer (score 4):

As weird as this may seem this is a TS feature. You can read some more about how functions are compared in TS [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).

In short TS allows for assignment of functions that have less parameters than the assignable type. The TS wording for this is **discarding parameters**.

The reason for this is how JS is used. There are a lot of APIs, some related to array, that allow for setting callbacks that have less parameters. If TS would impose this then a lot of existing code would break.

The main reason for this is that JS accepts optional parameters by default, so a function that has less parameters is always assignable to one that has more.

A note: if you actually call the function then TS will kick in as seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYBVzQLxQBQDMCWATgM7AByAhgLYQBcUph+CA5gDRQA2FplN9jZiwCUUDAD4GwJqwDcAKCQB7BKSgsIweJ0586sRKnRicoiVABEFhfI1a4OvdmFA)